# Test for an element to exist only once in Jest/RTL

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a component with which you can add sub-components by pressing on a '+' icon.

The rendered HTML is somewhere in the lines of:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      From <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
      To <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in the initial test, I test for the text to be there:

```js
// test setup

test('From and to occur only once', () => {
  const { getByText } = setup();

  expect(getByText('From')).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(getByText('To')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This all works perfectly fine. But I want to make sure initially **the content is shown only once**.

So my next test would be something in the lines of:

```js
// test setup

test('When add button is clicked there From and To exist two times', () => {
  const { getByText } = setup();
  const addButton = getByText("+")

  // first row
  expect(getByText('From')).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(getByText('To')).toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent.click(addButton);

  // second row
  expect(getByText('From')).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(getByText('To')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

How would I make a differentiation between the first and second time the elements occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using getAllBy (after the click) instead of getBy.  That can produce an array of all the elements found and you can expect() the total length of that to be 2.